# No permitir poner texto en una caja de texto NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos

Quiero almacenar números usando NSTextField, no permitiendo escribir texto en el campo de texto o bien controlandolo usando un `if(es texto) then no almacenar`
Que sería en el segundo caso "es texto"?

Comment: Bienvenido te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que asignarle un formato al textfield, intenta esto:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[textField setFormatter:formatter];
```